# In Android.mk, how to copy all the files in a directory recursively to out/vendor/ directory

Tags: android, android-build, android.mk

**I have a folder structure as following.**

```
sdk
├── 1.txt
├── 2.txt
└── install
    ├── bin
    │   └── 3.txt
    └── lib
        └── 4.txt
```

**I want to copy all these files to vendor/etc/ using Android.mk.**


**My sample Android.mk code:**

```
SDK_SRC_DIR = sdk

PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += \
        $(foreach f,$(wildcard $(SDK_SRC_DIR)/*/*),$(f):$(subst $(SDK_SRC_DIR),$(TARGET_COPY_OUT_VENDOR)/etc/,$(f)))
```

**I get an error as following while building.**

> [  3% 1/31] Copy: out/target/product/hikey960/vendor/sdk/install/bin
>   FAILED: out/target/product/hikey960/vendor/sdk/install/bin
>   /bin/bash -c "(rm -f out/target/product/hikey960/vendor/sdk/install/bin ) && (cp \"sdk/install/bin\" \"out/target/product/hikey960/vendor/sdk/install/bin\" )"
>
> **cp: omitting directory 'sdk/install/bin'**
>
> [  6% 2/31] Copy: out/target/product/hikey960/vendor/sdk/install/lib
>   FAILED: out/target/product/hikey960/vendor/sdk/install/lib
>   /bin/bash -c "(rm -f out/target/product/hikey960/vendor/sdk/install/lib ) && (cp \"sdk/install/lib\" \"out/target/product/hikey960/vendor/sdk/install/lib\" )"
>
> **cp: omitting directory 'sdk/install/lib'**

**So how to copy properly?**